# SQL OUTER JOIN statements and subqueries in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

LibraryDB is a database system that keeps track of information concerning the books and their circulation in an imaginary library.

The schema for the LibraryDB database is given below:

- borrow(transactionID, personID*, borrowdate, duedate, returndate)
- author(authorID, firstname, middlename, lastname)
- book_copy(bookID, bookdescID*)
- book(bookdescID, title, subtitle, edition, voltitle, volnumber, language, place, year, isbn, dewey, subjectID*)
- borrow_copy(transactionID*, bookID*)
- person(personID, firstname, middlename, lastname, address, city, postcode, phonenumber, emailaddress, studentno, idcardno)
- publisher(publisherID, publisherfullname)
- written_by(bookdescID*, authorID*, role)
- published_by(bookdescID*, publisherID*, role)
- subject(subjectID, subjecttype)

The primary keys are underlined. The foreign keys are denoted by asterisks (*).

Write an SQL query to display the titles of books that were never borrowed.

a.  Write your query using LEFT OUTER JOINs.

b.  Write the query again using subqueries and without using OUTER JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below queries

```
select b.title from book b
inner join book_copy bc
on (b.bookdescID = bc.bookdescID)
left outer join borrow_copy boc
on (bc.bookID = boc.bookID)
where boc.bookID is null;


select title from book where bookdescID in 
(select bookdescID from book_copy where bookID not in 
(select bookID from borrow_copy));
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why you're not using the AS statement to assign aliases to the relations by using statements like `SELECT title
FROM book AS b INNER JOIN book_copy AS bc`? And why you're using bc.title without defining what bc is first?When I tried to run the first query in SQLite, it returned an error message saying "no such column: bc.title".

Comment: My bad. Its b.title. And regarding aliases, its optional to use he functonality